# Deserialize a json string to an object variable in C#

Tags: c#, json, type-conversion, deserialization

I have the following code:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost/test-request", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var responseJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);

Console.WriteLine("Finished");

MessageBox.Show("Hi", responseJSON.value, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

The responseString comes back properly but i'm trying to convert it to an object so I can do more advanced stuff with the return value.

The problem is, C# / Visual Studio is complaining that responseJSON.value does not have a value (which it doesn't until the Async operation is complete)

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: You are attempting to deserialize to `object`, that's likely the problem. The asynchronous part of the function is done much earlier than that

Comment: You might want `JObject.Parse(responseJson)` or you might want to create a class that represents the json schema and deserialize to that specific type.

Comment: you can deseiralize to dynamic if you do not have a concrete class available

Comment: Could you return an instance directly using [ReadAsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541(v=vs.118).aspx)? E.g. `var response = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyClass>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var responseJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
```

creates responseJSON as a JSON.net JSObject.

You need either

```
var responseJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(responseString);
```

or

```
dynamic responseJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
```